# Api integration with nodejs and to get the values

Tags: node.js

How to integrate api with nodejs?
Using api,i want to get all the values in nodejs
**I want a detail coding for this.**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the stackoverflow help center.  There are a bunch of problems here.  First, it is not clear what you are asking.  Second, we do not just write code for you upon demand.  Third, if you want help with your problem, then you must write a specific question with a specific problem and show the code you've tried and exactly where you got stuck.  Fourth, you don't integrate an API with node.js.  You could implement an API in node.js.

Comment: Fifth, "get all values in nodejs" does not make sense.  nodejs does not generically have any values.  It is a programming environment that can be used to get things (from files, databases, other server, sensors, etc..) or calculate things or a lot of other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shobana you can get results from any APIs using a curl or http request. Following is a code snippet you can give a try.

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'url_link',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {"key1":value1,"key2":value2,"key3":value3}
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
    {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```